# $S_{10}$, the symmetric group and GAP

Tags: gap-system

Here is a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/453706/8581). As you see, the problem's established on finding an element of a certain order in $S_{10}$. I tried to do this question by using GAP. But, GAP couldn't handle the symmetric group $S_{10}$. What can we do in this situation? Is there a way for defining this large finite group for GAP? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "GAP couldn't handle the symmetric group $S_{10}$"? Please tell what exactly have you tried and what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be really interested to see what you've tried. Anyhow, and in particular, for the symmetric group where conjugacy classes are well known, you can easily examine orders of their representatives:

```gap
gap> 15 in List(ConjugacyClasses(SymmetricGroup(10)),c->Order(Representative(c)));
true
```

Moreover, you can use the character table library without even constructing the group itself:

```gap
gap> 15 in OrdersClassRepresentatives(CharacterTable("S10"));
true
```